# regular expression to match outside angle brackets

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace everything outside angle brackets

example
input String:

```
hello <how> are you <I'm fine> thanks. <what "about" you>, I'm fine as well thank you.
```

output String:

```
* <how> * * <I'm fine> *. <what "about" you>, * * * * * *.
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. What devnull means is: You haven't asked a question. Which part of the problem are you having trouble with? What have you tried, and why didn't it work as you expected?

Comment: I'm hoping that you are not trying to process HTML with regex.

Comment: What language are u using ?

Comment: @AlexW I don't think it's HTML.

Comment: @AmitJoki: Since you removed your answer, I can't comment on it. Just to explain the downvote: Your regex matched the *entire text*  between two tags, instead of each word separately (as the OP expects).

Comment: fine. Just explain what does _OP_ mean

Comment: @AmitJoki: [Original Poster](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=op)

Comment: you shouldn't need a regular expression for this

Comment: @nmclean i'll delete it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the language/tool is unknown, you can try this:

```
search: ((?:<[^>]*>|[.,\s])*)[^\s,.<]+((?:<[^>]*>|[.,\s])*)
replace: $1*$2
```

Comment: See it live: http://regex101.com/r/eC6oV5

Comment: If the last  part of input string is inside angle-bracket. this yields  unexpected result. For example: `a <b>` become `* <*`.

Comment: @falsetru: You are right, it's now corrected.